# Regex non-greedy named capturing groups

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I need to parse the below text and read the value for id and name, and *name is optional*. I am getting 'txt" name="thistext' as the value for id.

> input id="txt" name="thistext"

This is the regex I am using -

> `input\s+id="(?<id>.*)("+?)(?:(\s+name="(?<name>.*)(.*?")))?`

Full match  0-30    `input id="txt" name="thistext"`
Group `id`  10-29   `txt" name="thistext`
Group 2.    29-30   `"`

Comment: can you add sample input and expected output? and also what you already got so far?

Comment: you try this `input\s+id="(?<id>.*?)(?:"+?)(?:(\s+name="(?<name>.*?)(.*?")))?` https://regex101.com/r/KlTuJu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex was almost correct except, you needed to do non-greedy capture in your `id` named group and change your regex to this,

```
input\s+id="(?<id>.*?)("+?)(?:(\s+name="(?<name>.*)(.*?")))?
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p2ysHT/1)**

Also, your regex is uselessly overly complex which you can simplify as this,

```
input\s+id="(?<id>[^"]*)"(?:\s+name="(?<name>[^"]*)")?
```

**[Demo for better regex](https://regex101.com/r/kGu63L/1)**